# Limit multidimensional array to X arrays inside

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimentional array like this:

```
$my_array = array(

    array($user_id, $id, $type, $log, $url, $timestamp),
    array($user_id, $id, $type, $log, $url, $timestamp),
    array($user_id, $id, $type, $log, $url, $timestamp),
    // and so on...
);
```

`$my_array` has a random amount of arrays inside. I want to limit the amount of arrays to 5 inside `$my_array`. How can I achieve this? So, if there are 5 arrays inside, and one more is added, then remove the last array...

Comment: add an element and then [array_slice](http://www.php.net/array_slice)($array, -5)?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Can you please post an answer detailing how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new value and then call [array_slice](http://www.php.net/).

If you want to add to the end of the array:

```
//array with more than 5
$array = range(1, 8);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
//add the element
$array[] = 9;
//get the last 5
$array = array_slice($array, -5);

//output: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/DL91ZK

If you want to add to the beginning of the array

```
//array with more than 5
$array = range(1, 8); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
//add to the array
array_unshift($array, 0);
//get the first 5
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 5);

//output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/RGfohJ

Answer (score 2):

Just use a function to add arrays to it, then do your checks. E.g

```
function addToArray($arr, $newValue, $limit=5) {
    if (count($arr) >= $limit) {
        array_shift($arr);
    }
    $arr[] = $newValue;

    return $arr;
}
```

The function array_shift removes the first element and returns the shortened array.

If it is possible for things to be added to the array outside of this function, you can generalize:

```
function addToArray($arr, $newValue, $limit=5) {
    while (count($arr) >= $limit) {
        array_shift($arr);
    }
    $arr[] = $newValue;

    return $arr;
}
```

EDIT: Added improvements suggested by Jonathan Kuhn.

Comment: Just some clarification. Within the function, do I return the $my_array variable?

Comment: First, if the array has more than 5 elements, this will only remove 1. Second, array_shift takes the array be reference and returns the shifted value, not the original array with 1 less element. The original array is modified to be 1 less.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the brain fade when writing array_shift. You are correct that the original did not consider that entries could be added to the array outside of this function. I added a variation based on your suggestion.

Comment: One other small issue is that `$my_array` is not defined inside of the function. Also, you are returning nothing.

Comment: Yes, returning the result makes the function more flexible. Otherwise, $my_array needs to be global.

Comment: You could also pass in `$my_array` to the function. Your argument list should likely be more like `function addToArray(&$arr, $newValue, $limit=5)`. Then you would use it by calling `addToArray($array, 8)`. You would pass in `$arr` by reference and array_shift off that and add `$newValue` at the end.

Comment: Yes, I added most of your suggestions. I did not add the pass-by-reference. That would certainly work, but I generally avoid functions that affect the original variable, although in this case that would probably be OK.

Comment: Nice. I only suggested the pass by reference because you were suggesting to make the variable global which modifying the global variable would change it in the global scope. Normally I wouldn't use reference either in favor of return.